# Exporting all symbols in Julia

Tags: module, export, julia

Is there a way to export all symbols in a Julia module (something like the semantic counterpart to `importall`)? Such a functionality would be very useful when the number of symbols to be exported grows large. TIA.

Comment: This has been brought up multiple times on the mailing list and bugtracker, but has not found support. (Frankly, importall shouldn't exist.)

Comment: this feature is on V0.6.0 TODO list check https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/milestone/20 & related issue https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1986

Comment: @RezaAfzalan I do not find on v0.6

Comment: [#1986](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/1986) didn't land in 0.6, its current milestone is 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the [Reexport.jl](https://github.com/simonster/Reexport.jl) package that provides a form of this; it's use case is when you have a submodule and you want to reexport all of the exported symbols from the inner module into your current module. I know, not `exportall`, but part of the functionality.

Comment: Thank you. This will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a minimal [ExportAll.jl](https://github.com/JKRT/ExportAll.jl) package. It works and is tested for Julia 1.1.1 and it is available as a Julia package. Basically, it exports all symbols(!) defined in a module that is not part of any of the core modules. Disclaimer doing things like this is not good practice and should only be done with great care.