# Change REPL module/namespace in Julia

Tags: module, namespaces, julia, read-eval-print-loop

I'm looking for a way to "enter" a module in the REPL, so that I can access *all* symbols without qualification (not just the exported ones), and any function (re)defined at the REPL gets in the specified module. (Basically this is the functionality of Common Lisp's `in-package` macro.)

This would be useful in a REPL-oriented workflow, as I would be able to write the same code in the REPL as in the module I am developing.

The manual [recommends a workflow](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/workflow-tips/) where I qualify everything, but that seems annoying.

Comment: I started REPLmods.jl a while ago: https://github.com/spencerlyon2/REPLMods.jl

Comment: Nice! Exactly what I needed, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I started a package called [REPLMods.jl](https://github.com/spencerlyon2/REPLMods.jl) for this a while back. It should probably be polished up, but I haven't had the time.

I spoke to core Julia members and there was interest in getting it merged into base once things were clean, but again, no time!

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't quite what you're asking, but just in case the 'obvious' had not occured to you (or future visitors to the question), assuming you loaded a module with an annoyingly cumbersome name, e.g.

```
import LaTeXStrings
```

and you don't want to have to type LaTeXStrings all the time just to explore its accessibles, i.e.

```
LaTeXStrings.[TAB]
```

you can just assign the imported module as a whole to another variable, i.e.

```
const l = LaTeXStrings
```

I'm sure in the absence of a more appropriate built-in solution, at least typing `l.[TAB]` as opposed to `LaTeXStrings.[TAB]`is a lot more tolerable :)

(I find it odd, in fact, that julia doesn't seem to support the `import LaTeXStrings as l` syntax ...)

Comment: This can also be easily accomplished using a macro, like this [`@import`](https://gist.github.com/Ismael-VC/7f44ff56aa53ab2df42dff81fa8feb52#file-juliarc-jl-L18-L21) one I use in my `~/.juliarc.jl`:  `@import Foo as f`, which expands exactly to your example.

Answer (score 1):

It's 2020, I'm using Julia 1.4, and was unable to get [REPLMods.jl](https://github.com/spencerlyon2/REPLMods.jl) to work. I think the following seem good enough for the time being:

- [ExportAll.jl](https://github.com/JKRT/ExportAll.jl) - see [Exporting all symbols in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203560/exporting-all-symbols-in-julia) for a discussion (just that one shouldn't ExportAll to replace normal `export`)
- and [Revise.jl](https://github.com/timholy/Revise.jl)